# Difference between $ SU(3)$ and $ SU(3)_c $ group

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory, notation, quantum-chromodynamics

I am reading quark model. I don't understand what's the meaning of a color $SU(3)$ or $SU(3)_c$ group and how it differs from a general $SU(3)$ group. Please elaborate.

Comment: Reading where? Which page?

Comment: I don't think my question requires that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are mathematically the same group (i.e they are isomorphic)  but physically different. The colour group acts only on  the colour degrees of freedom while the  the orginal Gell-Man-Ne'eman flavour group  acts  on the $u,d,s$ flavours.  You can think of the quarks (in the case of three flavours only) having two sets of indices $q_{ij}$ where the $q_{1j}=u_j$  $q_{2j}=d_j$, $q_{3j}=s_j$, where  the $j$ index, taking values 1,2,3,  lables  the colour which couples to the gauge fields.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it completely now.

Answer (score 1):

The $c$ subscript merely denotes what property the group acts on. If the particles transform under multiple groups this will help clarify the structure. For instance the up and down quarks transform between each other under "isospin" which is $SU(2)$, but they also transform under color which is $SU(3)$. To clarify you could say that a quark multiplet is in the fundamental representation of $SU(2)_I\times SU(3)_c$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.